# Why does the Saint call Bosley "Bombay Sister"?

Tags: dialogue, charlies-angels

In *Charlie's Angels* (2019), Bosley meets The Saint:

> Saint: Hey. **Bombay sister**. How are you?
>
> Bosley: Master.

Why does he call her "Bombay Sister"?

Comment: Because Bombay Sister sound similar to Bosley and jokes based on names are funny?